# Why doesn't my Galaxy S2 see my keyboard/mouse?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, keyboard, mouse

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 and Android 4.0.3. It recognises all the mass storage devices but doesn't seem to see a mouse and keyboard. The mouse was for sure working with Android 2.3 but now it is transparent to the phone, which acts as if no devices have been plugged in. I've seen some Youtube videos where it was all working perfectly fine. What might be causing it?

On one forum I've read that the version of firmware that I have (I9100XXLPQ) doesn't support mouse and keyboard but I tried to research this information and confirm it with no success. Can anybody confirm/deny it or give some website I could consult?

Comment: what BT profile does your does you Keyboard and Mouse use. if they are using HID then switch them 2 SPP if possible then try.

Comment: But they are not visible to the phone when I plug them in, so how do I change the interface from HID?

Answer (score 1):

Try flashing your SGS2 with the siyah kernel. It proved effective for me. Grab the latest version of the kernel from the official [site](http://www.gokhanmoral.com/)

I am able to connect flash drives, mouse and keyboard. Yet to test with external HDD with and without external power. Please post if you come up with any other device that can be connected